# Micronaut @Requires annotation not respected in pipeline

Tags: java, continuous-integration, micronaut

I have built a Micronaut application which so far has not had any CI pipeline. All builds work flawlessly on all developer computers, but I can't for the life of me get it to run in a pipeline.

The issue is that I have a service annotated with `@Context`, meaning I want it to start at application startup:

```java
@Context
@Requires(property = "broker.subscribe.exchanges", env = { "k8s", "local" })
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.MESSAGE_CONSUMER)
public class SubscriberService {

    private final BrokerSubscriber subscriber;

    public SubscriberService(final BrokerSubscriber subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }
}
```

This just starts subscribing to a number of exchanges. I've added `env` to the annotation to ensure these do not start when running tests. If I remove the `env` property from the annotation, I get one failing test.

The code running in the pipeline has the `env` property set on the annotation, but it is not respected. When I run `./gradlew clean test` in the pipeline, the exact same test that fail without the `env` property set locally fail.

The test in question tests a configuration object, and is not annotated with `@MicronautTest`, however it does start an `ApplicationContext`:

```java
class BrokerConfigurationTest {

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        final Map<String, Object> items = new HashMap<>();
        items.put(getKey("server.host"), HOST);
        items.put(getKey("server.port"), PORT);
        items.put(getKey("server.password"), PASSWORD);
        items.put(getKey("server.user"), USER);
        items.put(getKey("subscribe.exchanges"), Set.of(EXCHANGE));

        // Explicitly not loading anything else.
        ctx = ApplicationContext.builder().packages(BrokerConfigurationTest.class.getPackageName()).properties(items).start();
        // Same result:
        // ctx = ApplicationContext.builder().environments("asdf").properties(items).start();
        // Same result:
        // ctx = ApplicationContext.run(items);
    }
}
```

What actually does work is removing the following line:

```java
items.put(getKey("subscribe.exchanges"), Set.of(EXCHANGE));
```

Meaning that the `@Requires` annotation is not fulfilled in regards to its `property`:

```java
@Requires(property = "broker.subscribe.exchanges", env = { "k8s", "local" })
```

With this setup, I can even remove the `env` property in the annotation and it works. But I *need* to test the behavior of this property, so this is not solution.

What I've tried that does not work:

1. Disable environment deduction with `./gradlew -Dmicronaut.env.deduction=false clean test`
2. Adding env variable `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS` set to `ci` in the pipeline build, and adding `notEnv = { "ci" }` in the `Requires`-annotation.
3. Both of the above at the same time
4. Explicitly telling the failing tests not to scan for anything outside of their own packages
5. Explicitly setting the environment to something other than `k8s` or `local` in the setup of the test.

Super smooth experience with the framework so far, but this has me scratching my head. Any input on what might be off here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue (Micronaut 2.5.13), and I failed. I created a similar bean with the `@Requires(property = "broker.subscribe.exchanges", notEnv = {"ci"})` annotation, so it was initialized when I run the test inside IntelliJ (or by `./gradlew test`). Then I run the test with the `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=ci ./gradlew test` and the bean was not initialized as expected. Could you provide a small example project that reproduces the issue? I suspect two things: either the env variable you set is not read in the pipeline, or something else overrides the envs.

Comment: "however it does start an ApplicationContext" - Are you saying that `ApplicationContext.builder().packages(BrokerConfigurationTest.class.getPackageName()).properties(items).start()` does not start the context?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Sorry, should have been clearer. Everything works locally, I don't even need the `notEnv` property of the annotation. I only used `k8s` and `local` in the `env` property, and since none of those are fulfilled when running `./gradlew test`, it works as it should. This issue is only present when running in Bitbucket. This is why I thought disabling `deduceEnv` would fix it, since but unfortunatley it did not.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown it does start a context, otherwise the tests would fail. i'm just pointing out that the `@MicronautTest` annotation is missing here (with all the effects that this annotation entails)

Comment: @jokarl, you have to investigate your Bitbucket's pipeline test runtime environment. Keep in mind that the `@Requires` annotation gets satisfied when any of `property` or `env` options are true. If running `./gradlew test` with the same code does not fail the test in the local env, but it only fails in the pipeline, it would suggest that the `broker.subscribe.exchanges` is provided in your CI environment. You need to figure out what sets this property.

Comment: The property does get set in the tests: `items.put(getKey("subscribe.exchanges"), Set.of(EXCHANGE));`. I want to start this class when _both_ this and any of the environments are a match. I expected `deduceEnv` to disable any automatically detected envs, hence nothing should match `env` in the annotation. Since that didn't work, I tried explicitly adding another environment that I called `ci` that I set as an environment variable only in pipelines, but that didn't work either. I will try to get some more logging in place when running the pipeline, I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult.